# How to Integrate Jconsole(Jdk/bin) with SpringBoot Application to manage dynamic logger configuration

Tags: spring-boot

Can someone help on to configure SpringBoot Application with Jconsole for dynamic logger configuration.

Below is the code setup :
Thanks

Comment: Below is the code setup :   where is code ??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to configure Jconsole , able to set the dynamic logging through this Jconsole

step 1->  Add  Property in application.property file 
     spring.jmx.enabled=true

Step 2 -> Create LogConfig class to set log level to to LoggerContext.below is the code

@Component
@ManagedResource(objectName = "OfferingService:name=MyCustomLogging", description = "Logging", log = true, logFile = "jmx.log", currencyTimeLimit = 15, persistPolicy = "OnUpdate", persistPeriod = 200, persistLocation = "logging", persistName = "logging")

public class LoggerConfig{

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerConfig.class);
@ManagedOperation(description = "Set the logging level for a category")
@ManagedOperationParameters( { @ManagedOperationParameter(name = "category", description = "Logger category"),
    @ManagedOperationParameter(name = "level", description = "Logging level") })
public void updatLoggerLevel(String category, String logLevel) {
    logger.info("updatLoggerLevel Method ================ >>>>: " + category);
    logger.info("LogLevel ================ >>>>: " + logLevel);
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    if (logLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("DEBUG")) {
        loggerContext.getLogger(category).setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    } else if (logLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("INFO")) {
        loggerContext.getLogger(category).setLevel(Level.INFO);
    } else if (logLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("TRACE")) {
        loggerContext.getLogger(category).setLevel(Level.TRACE);
    } else {
        logger.error(" Unknown loglevel: " + logLevel);
    }
}
@ManagedOperation(description = "Get the logging level for a category")
@ManagedOperationParameters( { @ManagedOperationParameter(name = "category", description = "Logger category") })
public String getLoggerLevel(String category) {
    logger.info("getLoggerLevel Method ================ >>>>: " + category);
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    return loggerContext.getLogger(category).getLevel().toString(); 
} }
```

Step 3 -> Run the springBoot application

step 4 -> Go to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin

Step 5- > Open JConsole and you can able to see the objectName = "MyApp" in Jconsole.

Step 6- > go to the operation , there you could see the Operation Name –> 
    updatLoggerLevel (this is method name)
this method can be fire from Jconsole by providing parame`enter code here`ters like one is packaageName and other is loglevel . this will override the existing log configuration.